# setTitle() behaves differently at different times

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I'm extending `AppCompatActivity` and setting `ActionBar` using `setSupportActionBar()`.

There's a bit of confusion in setting the title.

If I do -

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.titlebar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Title 1"); // Does not work
setTitle("Title 2"); // Works
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title 3"); // Works
setTitle("Title 4"); // Does not work. Why?
```

What I see is that `getSupportActionBar().setTitle()` is creating a new view for the title and then the activity is losing the reference to it. 
Is this the intended behavior or a bug in Android?

Answer (score 1):

If you call `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar),` then the Action Bar is then responsible for handling the title, therefore you need to call `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");` to set a custom title.

Also check this link where `toolbar.setTitle("My title");` may cause problem like below:- In android app `Toolbar.setTitle` method has no effect – application name is shown as title

And `toolbar` is the general form of action bar.

We can have multiple toolbars as layout widget but action is not.

Thus better approach is to use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");`

Comment: Your answer didn't convinced me why toolbar.setTitle(); not working in this case..

Answer (score 1):

copy this line

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

add the end of your line.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.titlebar);    
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Title 1");
setTitle("Title 2");
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title 3");
setTitle("Title 4");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: And then we get a NPE in line #4? ;)

Comment: you can use setSupportActionBar(); two times. one before line#4 and one at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's an intended behaviour once your set `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`. support library internal creates new view for display title.

`setTitle()` is method of `Activity` it'll update only title if used `setActionBar(Toolbar)`. But, it doesn't have backward compatability.

Ref

[AppCompatDelegateImplBase](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java#287)

[AppCompatDelegateImplV9](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java#629)

Comment: I understand that. But if the line 4 works, then the line 6 should also work.